# json data load into mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, json

I have a Json file :

```
      "db_name": "university_database",
      "tables": {

        "student": [
          {
            "ssn": 10,
            "name": "New",
            "major": "OR",
            "status": "active"
          },
          {
            "ssn": 75,
            "name": "Green",
            "major": "OR",
            "status": "active"
          },
```

I have tried the below code :

```
    import json
    import mysql.connector    

    f=open(univDB,"r")
    input=json.loads(f.read())

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
              host="localhost",
              user="usr",
              passwd="pas",
              database="db"
              )
            cursor = mydb.cursor()

            for i,item in input["tables"].items():

                    if(i=='student' or i=='class'):
                            print(i)
#inserting data into the student table 
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO student (ssn,name,major,status ) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (student["ssn"],student["name"], student["major"],student["status"]))


                                                        ha3("sampleUnivDB.json")
```

I need to load the json file into mysql database .however I keep getting an error in the execute statement .
after the forloop , it prints the values student and class . but Im  not sure if the syntax is correct for the 'insert into mysql db '

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: `i["ssn"],i["name"], i["major"],i["status"]`

Comment: @BradKellogg  get the error that student is not defined however I changed the code to i["ssn"],i["name"], i["major"],i["status"] in the execute statement i now get the error ->                                                                                                                                                                                "cursor.execute("INSERT INTO student (ssn,name,major,status ) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (i["ssn"],i["name"], i["major"],i["status"]))"
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @temmo  thank you for the help , initially when I tried it i got a very odd error .however I have to fix the integer thing and string error .

Comment: Can you put the cursor.execute code inside the for loop? After you try that, do the same thing with `i["ssn"],i["name"],`etc

Comment: still the same issue @BradKellogg

Comment: So you added `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO student (ssn,name,major,status ) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (i["ssn"],i["name"], i["major"],i["status"]))` to your for loop and got the TypeError: indices must be integers? @RachaelDSouza

Comment: @BradKellogg yes , so In the for loop                                                              
 for i,item in input["tables"].items():

                    if(i=='student' or i=='class'):
                            print(i)                                                                                                 I changed the If statement to (i==['student'] or i==['class']) the code ran but data is not inserting into the mysql tables

Comment: @RachaelDSouza ok try one more thing, instead of i try item like so `(item["ssn"], item["name"], item["major"], item["status"])`

Comment: @BradKellogg I did use item["ssn"] ...etc  still the same issue ., actually I'm sill getting the string indices must be integers error .

Comment: Then what about `(item.ssn, item.name, item.major, item.status)` @RachaelDSouza

Comment: @BradKellogg nope that didnt work either

Comment: @RachaelDSouza what do i and item equal while in the context of your for loop?

Comment: @RachaelDSouza, as you mention in your previous comment that after updating `(i==['student'] or i==['class'])` code ran, but did not insert the data. Please add `mydb.commit()` at the end and try again. You need to commit the transaction to reflect changes.

Comment: @BradKellogg it works fine now! using mydb.commit()

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was resolved in the comments.